# How to use TStartMenuTreeFolderView

Tags: inno-setup

I am getting blank tree view for my Start menu folder browser form, I created using `TStartMenuFolderTreeView`.

I the problem that I do not call the `TStartMenuFolderTreeView.SetPaths`?

Here is the Inno Setup code:

```pascal
[Code]

var
  Form2: TSetupForm;
  GFLabel1: TLabel;
  GFButton1, GFButton2: TButton;
  gEdit: TEdit;
  GroupTreeView: TStartMenuFolderTreeView;

procedure Button1Click (Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.Close
  WizardForm.Enabled:=True;
  WizardForm.GroupEdit.Text:=gEdit.Text;
end;

procedure Button2Click (Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.Close
  WizardForm.Enabled:=True;
end;

procedure EditOnChange(Sender:Tobject);
begin
  gEdit.Text:=AddBackSlash(GroupTreeView.Directory) + '{#GroupName}';
end;

procedure Close (Sender:Tobject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Form2.close
  WizardForm.Enabled:=True;
end;

procedure GroupButtonClick(Sender:Tobject);
begin
  Form2:=CreateCustomForm;
  with Form2 do
  begin
    Width:=470;
    Height:=296;
    Position:=poScreenCenter;
    CenterInsideControl(WizardForm, False);
    Caption:='Browse For Folder';
    OnClose:=@Close;
  end;

  GFLabel1:=TLabel.Create(Form2);
  with GFLabel1 do
  begin
    Parent:=Form2;
    SetBounds(5,5,100,10)
    Caption:='Select a folder in list below, Then click OK.';
  end;

  GFButton1:=TButton.Create(Form2);
  with GFButton1 do
  begin
    Parent:=Form2;
    SetBounds(285,22,80,25)
    Caption:='OK';
    OnClick:=@Button1Click;
  end;

  GFButton2:=TButton.Create(Form2);
  with GFButton2 do
  begin
    Parent:=Form2;
    SetBounds(370,22,80,25)
    Caption:='Cancel';
    OnClick:=@Button2Click;
  end;

  gEdit:=TEdit.Create(Form2);
  with gEdit do
  begin
    Parent:=Form2;
    SetBounds(5,25,275,15)
    Text:=WizardForm.GroupEdit.Text;
    OnChange:=@EditOnChange;
  end;

  GroupTreeView:=TStartMenuFolderTreeView.Create(Form2);
  with GroupTreeView do
  begin
    Parent:=Form2;
    SetBounds(5,53,445,205)
    OnChange:=@EditOnChange;
  end;

  GroupTreeView.ChangeDirectory(AddBackslash(WizardForm.GroupEdit.Text), true);
  gEdit.Text:=AddBackslash(GroupTreeView.Directory);
  Form2.Show;
  WizardForm.Enabled:=false;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  with WizardForm.GroupBrowseButton do
  begin
    OnClick:=@GroupButtonClick;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: As I've told you already, the code must be in the question! No external links!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to call `TStartMenuFolderTreeView.SetPaths`:

```pascal
GroupTreeView.SetPaths(
  ExpandConstant('{userprograms}'),
  ExpandConstant('{commonprograms}'),
  ExpandConstant('{userstartup}'),
  ExpandConstant('{commonstartup}'));
```

---

On top of that, your implementation of the form execution is completely wrong.

You have to use `TForm.ShowModal` for modal dialogs, not `TForm.Show`. Then, you won't have to do all that main form disabling/enabling (what does not work anyway, your code crashes for me every time I close the dialog).

You also do not need the `TButton.OnClick`. Use `TButton.ModalResult` to get the buttons close the dialog automatically. Additionally, for "OK" button, set the `TButton.Default`, for "Cancel" button, set the `TButton.Cancel`. This makes <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> keys working.

```pascal
with GFButton1 do
begin
  { ... }
  Default := True;
  ModalResult := mrOK;
end;

with GFButton2 do
begin
  { ... }
  Cancel := True;
  ModalResult := mrCancel;
end;

{ ... }

if Form2.ShowModal = mrOK then
begin
  WizardForm.GroupEdit.Text := gEdit.Text;
end;
```

And remove the `Button1Click`, `Button2Click` and `Close`.

---

More observations:

- No need for all those global variables. They all can be local to the `GroupButtonClick`.
- Assigning the `EditOnChange` to the `gEdit.OnChange` is nonsense. It will prevent you from editing the folder path manually.
- Do not use fixed sizes and offsets. Always use [`ScaleX`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_scalex) and [`ScaleY`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_scaley) functions.
  E.g. `Width := ScaleX(470);`
  Otherwise your dialog will be small on high-DPI displays.
  See [Inno Setup Placing image/control on custom page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43696537/850848).
- Note that in general, use of the Start menu groups is discouraged in recent version of Windows. There should be a single icon per application only.