# Placing image/control on Inno Setup custom page

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm trying to have an image on a custom page I can get the custom page to show or the image on a predefined page but not on the custom page.

Problem I think is with `Parent := CustomPage.ID;`.

`Parent := WizardForm.SelectTasksPage;` works though.

How to do this properly?

```pascal
procedure ImageOnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  ShellExec('', 'http://test.com', '', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
end;

var
  CustomPage: TWizardPage;
  BtnImage: TBitmapImage;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  CustomPage := CreateCustomPage(wpLicense, 'Heading', 'Sub heading.');

  ExtractTemporaryFile('image.bmp');

  BtnImage := TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
  with BtnImage do
  begin
    Parent := CustomPage.ID;
    Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}')+'\image.bmp');
    AutoSize := True;
    Left := 90;
    Top := WizardForm.SelectTasksPage.Top +
           WizardForm.SelectTasksPage.Height - Height - 8;
    Cursor := crHand;
    OnClick := @ImageOnClick;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's what `TWizardPage.Surface` of type `TNewNotebookPage` is for.

```pascal
with BtnImage do
begin
  Parent := CustomPage.Surface;
  { ... }
end;
```

Related questions:

- [TInputDirWizardPage with Radio Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49358778/850848)
  *(Similar question about radio buttons with more code)*
- [Add additional controls to standard Inno Setup pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65532874/850848)

---

Also, never use absolute coordinates and sizes. Your layout will break, when the wizard is shown on high DPI/scaled display, what is quite common nowadays with "retina" displays. Use [`ScaleX`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_scalex) and [`ScaleY`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_scaley) functions. For the same reason, you should have images with different resolutions ready (see [Inno Setup WizardImageFile looks bad with font scaling on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26543603/850848)). Or at least scale/stretch the bitmap.

```pascal
CustomPage := CreateCustomPage(wpLicense, 'Heading', 'Sub heading.');

ExtractTemporaryFile('image.bmp');

BtnImage := TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
with BtnImage do
begin
  Parent := CustomPage.Surface;
  Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}')+'\image.bmp');
  AutoSize := True;
  AutoSize := False;
  Height := ScaleY(Height);
  Width := ScaleX(Width);
  Stretch := True;
  Left := ScaleX(90);
  Top := WizardForm.SelectTasksPage.Top + WizardForm.SelectTasksPage.Height -
         Height - ScaleY(8);
  Cursor := crHand;
  OnClick := @ImageOnClick;
end;
```

Layout on 100% zoom (96 DPI):

[image: Layout on 100% zoom (96 DPI)]

Layout on 150% zoom (144 DPI):

[image: Layout on 150% zoom (144 DPI)]

Layout on 150% zoom (144 DPI) with offset/sizes scaling and image stretching:

[image: Layout on 150% zoom (144 DPI) with offset/sizes scaling and image stretching]

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Martin Prikryl's answer.
In order to deal with different DPI settings and placing a bitmap:

1. setup your machine to 100% DPI
2. make a bitmap with size (width/height) to fit on your InnoSetup page/form
3. get these width and height (right click/properties on your bmp file)
4. use the code below
5. setup your machine to 150% DPI and create your bitmap to fit for 150% DPI and use it instead the first one (which fits for 100% DPI), this way it will look nice for 100% and for 200%

The code:

```
WarningImage := TBitmapImage.Create(RisksForm);
WarningImage.Parent := RisksForm;
WarningImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{app}')+'uninstall-warning-large.bmp');
WarningImage.Left := ScaleX(24);
WarningImage.Top := ScaleY(120);
WarningImage.Width := ScaleX(544);
WarningImage.Height := ScaleY(211);
WarningImage.Stretch := True;
```

Change 544 with the width of your bitmap and 211 with the height of your bitmap (from step 3)

**Stretch := True** does the bitmap to expand (if it is smaller) or shrink (if it is bigger) than width/height properties

P.S. ofcourse you could use multiple files and use one depending on users DPI settings ([DPI settings with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585603/how-to-detect-and-fix-dpi-settings-with-inno-setup#27040035)), but bitmaps are without compressions, so I don't like this idea.

Answer (score -1):

you can Use Botva2 library 
http://krinkels.org/threads/botva2.1931/
use google translate if u can't understand rusian
u can create some awesome installer using this
image f.e
[Botva2 example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux6YI.jpg)

```
[code]
#include "botva2.iss"
var SomeImage : Longint;
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin 
{Your Custom page Code Goes Here}
SomeImage := ImgLoad(WizardForm.Handle,'Image.bmp',0,0,854,480,true,true)‌​; 
end;
 procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer); 
begin 
ImgSetVisibility(SomeImage,false); 
if (CurPageID = CustomPage.ID) ImgSetVisibility(SomeImage,true);
end;
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: SomeImage := ImgLoad(WizardForm.Handle,'Image.bmp',0,0,854,480,true,true);

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
ImgSetVisibility(SomeImage,false);
if (CurPageID = CustomPage.ID) ImgSetVisibility(SomeImage,true);

Comment: actually procedure InitializeWizard();
var SomeImage:Longint; {SomeImage Should be a global variable}
{CreateCustom Form Definition} 
SomeImage := ImgLoad(WizardForm.Handle,'Image.bmp',0,0,854,480,true,true)‌​;
end;

Comment: @PrinceGupta : please edit your answer and put code not in comments!

Comment: Using `CurPageChanged` to hide/show controls for respective page is a bad practice - Set control's parent to respective page instead! That's what the pages are for!

Comment: use CustomePage.Surface.handle instead of WizardForm.Handle, also after calling Imgload call ImgApplyChanges(Custompage.Surface.Handle)
this willl not require CurpageChanged function

Comment: If you know that, why does your answer show that bad solution?

Comment: for big scripts like https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux6YI.jpg - we prefer not to create new components to save startup time and uses CurpageChanged functions a lot