# Inno Setup - Customize installing page

Tags: inno-setup

How can I customize the installing page of Inno Setup?

Here exactly shows the changes that are going to be made.

Before

[image: before]

After

[image: after]

Now, status text 'Installing Collectica' will be static and not dynamic.

Also, adding extra time to the progress bar.

I will appreciate your answers. Thanks

Comment: The *"extra time"* part deserves more explanation, and probably a separate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to customize `WizardForm.InstallingPage`:

- Hide the `FilenameLabel` and `StatusLabel`
- Add you custom label
- Add the image

For the first two:

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  CustomStatusLabel: TNewStaticText;
begin
  WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Visible := False;
  WizardForm.StatusLabel.Visible := False;

  WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Top := WizardForm.InstallingPage.Height - ScaleY(60);

  CustomStatusLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  CustomStatusLabel.Parent := WizardForm.InstallingPage;
  CustomStatusLabel.Caption := 'Installing Colectica';
  CustomStatusLabel.Font.Size := CustomStatusLabel.Font.Size + 4;
  CustomStatusLabel.Font.Style := [fsBold];
  CustomStatusLabel.AutoSize := True;
  CustomStatusLabel.Top :=
    WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Top - CustomStatusLabel.Height - ScaleY(8);
  CustomStatusLabel.Left :=
    WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Left +
    ((WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Width - CustomStatusLabel.Width) div 2);
end;
```

[image]

For the image, see:
[Inno Setup Placing image/control on custom page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43696537/850848)

Comment: Exploring for ideas on Inno I found this, thank you.