# Inno Setup - How to add picture box to progress dialog?

Tags: inno-setup, progressdialog, wizard

This code adds a picture to the licnese agreement wizard page,

```
  picLicense := TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm.LicensePage);
  with picLicense do
  begin
    Parent := WizardForm.LicensePage;
    Left := ScaleX(0);
    Top := ScaleY(0);
    Width := ScaleX(100);
    Height := ScaleY(100);

    Stretch := True;
    Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\image.bmp'));
  end;
```

But how to add the image or any other custom control to progress dialog wizard page?

Comment: Use `InstallingPage` instead of `LicensePage`? – Is this what are you looking for? – [Inno Setup - Customize installing page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44835264/850848).

Comment: Yes, that is the one. Thanks. If you add an answer to this question with `InstallingPage`, then I'll select your answer.