# Why doesn't the radio button on custom page checked in Inno Setup?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

Why don't `rbStandardInstallType` and `rbCustomInstallType` radio buttons get checked even though I set the `Checked` property of one of those to `True`? On the other hand, `rbDefaultMSSQLInstance` and `rbNamedMSSQLInstance` radio buttons do get checked.

I create radio buttons like this:

```pascal
function CreateRadioButton(
  AParent: TNewNotebookPage; AChecked: Boolean; AWidth, ALeft, ATop, AFontSize: Integer;
  AFontStyle: TFontStyles; const ACaption: String): TNewRadioButton;
begin
  Result := TNewRadioButton.Create(WizardForm);
  with Result do
    begin
      Parent := AParent;
      Checked := AChecked;
      Width := AWidth;
      Left := ALeft;
      Top := ATop;
      Font.Size := AFontSize;
      Font.Style := AFontStyle;
      Caption := ACaption;
    end;
end;
```

I have 2 custom pages where I must show my image on the left and some text and radio buttons on the right (2 radio buttons per page).
So, in my `InitializeWizard` procedure I've written this:

```pascal
wpSelectInstallTypePage := CreateCustomPage(wpSelectDir, 'Caption', 'Description');
rbStandardInstallType := CreateRadioButton(WizardForm.InnerPage, True, WizardForm.InnerPage.Width, ScaleX(15), WizardForm.MainPanel.Top + ScaleY(30), 9, [fsBold], 'Standard');
rbCustomInstallType := CreateRadioButton(WizardForm.InnerPage, False, rbStandardInstallType.Width, rbStandardInstallType.Left, rbStandardInstallType.Top + rbStandardInstallType .Height + ScaleY(16), 9, [fsBold], 'Custom');

wpMSSQLInstallTypePage := CreateCustomPage(wpSelectInstallTypePage.ID, 'Caption2', 'Description2');
rbDefaultMSSQLInstance := CreateRadioButton(WizardForm.InnerPage, True, WizardForm.InnerPage.Width, ScaleX(15), WizardForm.MainPanel.Top + ScaleY(30), 9, [fsBold], 'DefaultInstance');
rbNamedMSSQLInstance := CreateRadioButton(WizardForm.InnerPage, False, rbDefaultMSSQLInstance.Width, rbDefaultMSSQLInstance.Left, rbDefaultMSSQLInstance.Top + rbDefaultMSSQLInstance.Height + ScaleY(10), 9, [fsBold], 'NamedInstance');
```

And finally, here's my `CurPageChanged` code in order to display all the controls properly:

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
  begin
    case CurPageID of
      wpSelectInstallTypePage.ID, wpMSSQLInstallTypePage.ID:
          WizardForm.InnerNotebook.Visible := False;  
    else
      WizardForm.InnerNotebook.Visible := True;
    end;
    rbDefaultMSSQLInstance.Visible := CurPageID = wpMSSQLInstallTypePage.ID;
    rbNamedMSSQLInstance.Visible := CurPageID = wpMSSQLInstallTypePage.ID;
    rbStandardInstallType.Visible := CurPageID = wpSelectInstallTypePage.ID;
    rbCustomInstallType.Visible := CurPageID = wpSelectInstallTypePage.ID;
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the radio buttons to a wrong parent control (`WizardForm.InnerPage`). Not to the custom pages you are creating. And you then workaround that flaw by explicitly hiding/showing the radio buttons in `CurPageChanged`.

As all four radio buttons have the same parent (`WizardForm.InnerPage`), only one of them can be checked. So when you check the `rbDefaultMSSQLInstance`, the `rbStandardInstallType` is implicitly unchecked.

---

For the correct code, see:
[Inno Setup Placing image/control on custom page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43696537/850848)

*(make sure you remove your redundant `CurPageChanged` code)*

---

You should also consider using [`CreateInputOptionPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createinputoptionpage) instead of manually adding the radio buttons to a generic custom page.