# When do I really need to use ScaleX and ScaleY functions in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Here's the documentation for `ScaleX` function: [ScaleX](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_scalex.htm). The same thing is for `ScaleY`: [ScaleY](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_scaley.htm). I'm a little bit confused with these. Does it mean that I only need to use them when I use different font sizes on my wizard page? Can anybody give me the real example of why I should always use those instead of absolute/relative values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use them always, when setting absolute control locations and sizes.

They take care of custom font sizes and window scaling set by the user in Windows preferences. That's not under your installer control.

See also [Inno Setup Placing image/control on custom page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43696537/850848).